# Configure to get the opaque token from FustionAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, fusionauth

When we authenticate user using FusionAuth, we are getting JWT token as the output. How to get the opaque token rather than JWT?

If it can be done, will introspect use opaque token to validate the JWT token generated?

Answer (score 0):

FusionAuth does not generate opaque access tokens.

You can treat them as opaque if you like, and then using the [Introspect endpoint](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/oauth/endpoints#introspect) FusionAuth will validate the token and return you a JSON response.